# python request equivalent to curl -L

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

curl -L retains headers across redirects.

I am currently looking at a third party URL which with a normal curl (allows redirects) is as follows  *(This is the same response I get using a python request.)*

```
$curl https://[xxx].fr/[xxxx]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>307 Temporary Redirect</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Temporary Redirect</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="/redirect?token=lfbzjv3m2yabpbb8tggjjmsgz2">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

using curl -L, I see the following

```
$curl -L https://[xxx].fr/[xxxx]
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Detection des bots</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Bot detecte.</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Despite that this reveals 3rd party cruft at the server, I want to ensure I get the "Detection des bots" message rather than the "307 Temporary Redirect" message.

I will include the actual url as a comment (and will subsequently delete it once a solution is found, as the url is likely to be modified).

My purpose is to provide a meaningful third party link status report - there is no malign intent. 'Detection des bots' is good enough for me.

Comment: https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/c_1099663/fr/certification-de-l-activite-d-information-promotionnelle

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python code that you want to grab data from the URL:

```py
import requests

url = "PUT-YOUR-URL-HERE"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I recommend to use user-agent and other request header parameters to not detected as a bot. You can use [user-agents](https://pypi.org/project/user-agents/) python library to generate custom user agents

Comment: Have you tried your snippet with the above url?

Comment: @Konchog which URL ? It was a sample url

Comment: https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/c_1099663/fr/certification-de-l-activite-d-information-promotionnelle  (it's in the comment).

Comment: @Konchog, I updated the code, you can use it, I test it with your URL and it works

Comment: Thanks - that gets the same as the result.. Still didn't return the same as curl -L.  Or is that solely to do with the user-agent?